# Enable server cache for a specific folder

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, caching, cache-control

I codded a php script that consiste to collect some informations using the (simple dom html) from some websites(from html).
my problem that every time when i launche the script it browses the all website selected and that takes over 20 sec per launche.
i want to set a server cache for a specific foler that contains the script (htdocs/folder/sript.php). i want to set server cache to execute the script one per 5 minites for example otherwise give the last resaults.
i already tried to add some lines to the .htaccess but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.4 you should use PHP opcache : http://php.net/manual/fr/opcache.installation.php

You can set a blacklist for caching : http://php.net/manual/fr/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.blacklist-filename

For PHP < 5.4 :

You should use PHP APC cache :

`sudo apt-get install php-apc`

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

After that you can use something like

apc.filters "[regex]" on your php.ini file

Comment: unfortunately my server is on PHP5.3

Comment: Ok, so you should use the APC cache. Updated answer.